# Publicar React.js servidor windows

Tags: node.js, windows, react

Tenho uma aplicação desenvolvida com React + React-Redux e agora que ela está finalizada preciso publicar. Porém ao pesquisar sobre isso não achei nada que explicasse ou tivesse um passo a passo de como realizar o deploy no windows server (usando o IIS ou não). Tudo que encontro é como fazer o deploy no heroku, netifly etc. Porém essa aplicação é interna e só irá rodar no ambiente interno. Talvez seja uma pergunta com uma resposta simples, no entanto não encontrei nenhum norte de como fazer isso.

Comment: Basta compilar e mandar os arquivos pro servidor, por FTP, por exemplo

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam então minha dúvida é: preciso configurar/instalar alguma coisa no meu server? tipo node.js? ou funciona como uma aplicação desenvolvida simplesmente com javascript/html?

Comment: Não, o código resultante da compilação está completo, ele irá rodar no browser, o servidor apenas fornece os arquivos

Answer (score 4):

Bastou executar **npm run build** e copiar os itens gerados na pasta build para o servidor desejado (no meu caso IIS).